# Linked list polynomial multiplication

Tags: c++, debugging, pointers, data-structures, linked-list

I have written a program to multiply two polynomials in the form of single linked lists. I am unable to print output using this code.

The output I am getting is

```
1st Number: 5x^2 + 4x^1 + 2x^0
2nd Number: 5x^1 + 5x^0
Multiplied polynomial:
```

How can I fix that?

My code:

```
// C++ program for multiplication of two polynomials
// using Linked Lists
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

// Node structure containing power and coefficient of variable
struct node
{
    int coeff;
    int exp;
    struct node *next;
};
void padd(float, int, node**);          
// Function to create new node
void create_node(int x, int y, struct node **temp)
{
    struct node *r,*z ;
    z = *temp;
    if(z == NULL)
    {
        r =(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        r->coeff = x;
        r->exp = y;
        *temp = r;
        r->next = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        r = r->next;
        r->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        r->coeff = x;
        r->exp = y;
        r->next = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        r = r->next;
        r->next = NULL;
    }
}

// Function Multiplying two polynomial numbers
void polymul ( struct node *poly1, struct node *poly2,
                   struct node *poly )
{
    struct node *y1 ;
    float coeff1;
    int exp1 ;

    y1 = poly2 ;  /* point to the starting of the second linked list */
if ( poly1 == NULL && poly2 == NULL )
        return ;

    /* if one of the list is empty */
if ( poly1 == NULL )
        poly = poly2 ;
    else
    {
        if ( poly2 == NULL )
            poly = poly1 ;
        else/* if both linked lists exist */

        {
            /* for each term of the first list */
            while ( poly1 != NULL )
            {
                /* multiply each term of the second linked list with a 
                    term of the first linked list */
                while ( poly2 != NULL )
                {
                    coeff1 = poly1 -> coeff * poly2 -> coeff ;
                    exp1 = poly1 -> exp + poly2 -> exp ;
                    poly2 = poly2 -> next ;

                    /* add the new term to the resultant polynomial */

                    padd ( coeff1, exp1, &poly ) ;
                }

                poly2 = y1 ;  /* reposition the pointer to the starting of
                         the second linked list */


                poly1 = poly1 -> next ;  /* go to the next node */

            }
        }
    }
}

/* adds a term to the polynomial in the descending order of the exponent */
void padd ( float coeff, int exp, struct node **s )
{
    struct node *r, *temp = *s ;

    /* if list is empty or if the node is to be inserted before the first node */
if ( *s == NULL || exp > ( *s ) -> exp )
    {
        *s=r = (struct node*) malloc ( sizeof ( struct node ) ) ;
        (*s) -> coeff = coeff ;
        (*s) -> exp = exp ;
        (*s)-> next = temp ;
    }
    else
    {
        /* traverse the entire linked list to search the position to insert a new node */
        while ( temp != NULL )
            {
                if ( temp -> exp == exp )
                {
                    temp -> coeff += coeff ;
                    return ;
                }

                if ( temp -> exp > exp && ( temp -> next -> exp < exp ||    temp -> next == NULL ) )
                    {
                        r = (struct node* )malloc ( sizeof ( struct node ) ) ;
                        r -> coeff = coeff;
                        r -> exp = exp ;
                        r -> next = temp -> next ;
                        temp -> next = r ;
                        return ;
                    }

            temp = temp -> next ;  /* go to next node */

            }

        r -> next = NULL ;
        temp -> next = r ;
    }
}

// Display Linked list
void show(struct node *node)
{
while(node->next != NULL)
    {
    printf("%dx^%d", node->coeff, node->exp);
    node = node->next;
    if(node->next != NULL)
        printf(" + ");
    }
}

// Driver program
int main()
{
    struct node *poly1 = NULL, *poly2 = NULL, *poly = NULL;

    // Create first list of 5x^2 + 4x^1 + 2x^0
    create_node(5,2,&poly1);
    create_node(4,1,&poly1);
    create_node(2,0,&poly1);

    // Create second list of 5x^1 + 5x^0
    create_node(5,1,&poly2);
    create_node(5,0,&poly2);

    printf("1st Number: "); 
    show(poly1);

    printf("\n2nd Number: ");
    show(poly2);

    poly = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    // Function multiply two polynomial numbers
    polymul(poly1, poly2, poly);

    // Display resultant List
    printf("\nMultiplied polynomial: ");
    show(poly);

return 0;
}
```

Comment: As a side note: declaring a `struct` automatically makes the `struct` name a type name and you do not need to repeat the `struct` word, Also, prefer `new` / `delete` over `malloc` / `free`. `malloc` does not call constructors and `new` does not require casting (nor does `malloc` in C).

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your function `padd()` before function `polymul`or you can write a function prototype at the top so that the compiler knows that the function `padd` will be encountered after `polymul`.

For the second error you should typecast the output of `malloc` function to `struct node *` as malloc returns `void *` type value.

Just add the typcasting to the `malloc` functions in your code.

```
r = (struct node*)malloc ( sizeof ( struct node ) ) ;
```

There were some pointer issues in the linked list. I have fixed them in the ideone link.

```
 #include<bits/stdc++.h>

   using namespace std;

// Node structure containing power and coefficient of variable

   struct node
   {
    int coeff;
    int exp;
    struct node *next;
};

// Function to create new node


void create_node(int x, int y, struct node **temp)
{

    struct node *r, *tmp=NULL ;

    if(*temp == NULL) // If the list is NULL then add node at First position
    {
        r =(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        r->coeff = x;
        r->exp = y;
        r->next = NULL;
        *temp = r;
        /*r->next = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
        r = r->next;
        r->next = NULL;*/ //Not needed
    }
    else
    {
        tmp = *temp;
        while (tmp->next != NULL) {
            tmp = tmp -> next; //Travel to the end of linked list
        }
        r = (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node)); 
        r->coeff = x;
        r->exp = y;
        r->next = NULL;
        tmp->next = r; //Add new node to the list

    }
}

// Function Adding two polynomial numbers

 /* adds a term to the polynomial in the descending order of the exponent */

    void padd ( int coeff, int exp, struct node **s )
   {
    struct node *r, *temp = *s ;
    struct node *tmp = *s;
    /* if list is empty or if the node is to be inserted before the first node 
    */



    if ( temp == NULL || exp > ( temp ) -> exp )

    {
        r = (struct node*)malloc ( sizeof ( struct node ) ) ;
        r -> coeff = coeff ;
        r -> exp = exp ;
        r -> next = temp ;
        temp = r;
        *s = r;
    }
    else
    {
        /* traverse the entire linked list to search the position to insert 
        a new node */
        while ( temp != NULL )
            {
                if ( temp -> exp == exp )
                {
                    temp -> coeff += coeff ;
                    return;
                } else if ( temp -> exp > exp && ( temp -> next -> exp < exp ||temp ->next == NULL ) )
                    {
                        r = (struct node*)malloc ( sizeof ( struct node ) ) ;
                        r -> coeff = coeff;
                        r -> exp = exp ;
                        r -> next = temp -> next ;
                        temp -> next = r ;
                        return;
                    }

                temp = temp -> next ;  /* go to next node */

            }

        r -> next = NULL ;
        temp -> next = r ;
    }
}

   struct node * polymul ( struct node *poly1, struct node *poly2, struct node *poly3)
   {

    struct node *y1 ;
    int coeff1;
    int exp1 ;

    struct node *poly = poly3;
    y1 = poly2 ;         /* point to the starting of the second linked list */
    if ( poly1 == NULL && poly2 == NULL )
        return NULL;

    /* if one of the list is empty */
    if ( poly1 == NULL ) {
        poly = poly2 ;
    } else
    {
        if ( poly2 == NULL )
            poly = poly1 ;
        else    /* if both linked lists exist */

        {
            /* for each term of the first list */
            while ( poly1 != NULL )
            {
                /* multiply each term of the second linked list with a 
                    term of the first linked list */
                while ( poly2 != NULL )
                {
                    coeff1 = poly1 -> coeff * poly2 -> coeff ;
                    exp1 = poly1 -> exp + poly2 -> exp ;
                    poly2 = poly2 -> next ;

                    /* add the new term to the resultant polynomial */

                    padd( coeff1, exp1, &poly) ;
                }

                poly2 = y1 ;  /* reposition the pointer to the starting of
                                the second linked list */


                poly1 = poly1 -> next ;  /* go to the next node */

            }
        }
    }
    return poly;
}



// Display Linked list
    void show(struct node *node)
    {
        while(node != NULL) // if we use node->next != NULL while will break at the last node skipping it
        {
            printf("%dx^%d", node->coeff, node->exp);

            if(node->next != NULL)
                printf(" + ");

            node = node->next;
        }
    }

// Driver program

    int main()
    {
    struct node *poly1 = NULL, *poly2 = NULL, *poly = NULL;

    // Create first list of 5x^2 + 4x^1 + 2x^0

    create_node(5,2,&poly1);
    create_node(4,1,&poly1);
    create_node(2,0,&poly1);

    // Create second list of 5x^1 + 5x^0

    create_node(5,1,&poly2);
    create_node(5,0,&poly2);

    printf("1st Number: "); 
    show(poly1);

    printf("\n2nd Number: ");
    show(poly2);

    poly = (struct node *)malloc(sizeof(struct node));

    // Function add two polynomial numbers

    poly = polymul(poly1, poly2, poly);

    // Display resultant List

    printf("\nAdded polynomial: ");
    show(poly);

return 0;
}
```

[Ideone Link](http://ideone.com/WooOh1)

Comment: It did fix my error. But now, I am unable to get desired output that is multiplication of two polynomials.

Comment: @JaiPrakash There are several errors in your linked list. You `ceate_node` function is wrong, your `show` function is wrong. You need to learn about linked lists and debug your code yourself.

Comment: I don't see how my create_node () function and show() function van be wrong. The only problem that I think is with pointers that are messing with this code.

Comment: @JaiPrakash You have created 2 polynomials `5x^2 + 4x^1 + 2x^0` and `5x^1 + 5x^0` but show function is only printing the first element. Your `create node` is not appending the nodes to the list. Also, your `show` function will not print the last node of the list. First, correct your code which is not working properly.

Comment: I am unable to debug this code. I have tried, tweaked and changed code many a times and failed. If you could point out my mistakes line by line, help will be much appreciated.

Comment: @JaiPrakash Give your latest attempted code. Let me help you debug.

Comment: @JaiPrakash I have updated the code. Now `create` and `show` are working.

Comment: The thing is I had already modified my show function, but it only prints last term of the polynomial even with your debug code. The output should be 25x^3+45x^2+30x^1+10x^0. The output that this code prints is 10x^0.

Comment: @JaiPrakash I just fixed the `create` and `debug` function!

Comment: @JaiPrakash Check the code now. I have fixed all the bugs. But you are making a lot of mistakes with pointers. Learn about the pointers otherwise you will again run into errors.